# Why does window.getComputedStyle() show discrepancies in value for width and height?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am having a pretty simple few lines to determine the computed width and height of a DOM element. Or so I thought:

```
const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);
// const width = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('width');
const width = computedStyle['width'];
console.log(width); // 'auto'
console.log("computed", computedStyle);
```

However, when I log the value for width, I am getting 'auto', no matter if I access it directly as a property or through the getPropertyValue getter. But when I just check the value in the log of the entire computedStyle object, I am getting the following:[image] which is clearly not the same.

What is the problem here? Does it have to do with the dynamic nature of getComputedStyle, aka is 'auto' the initial value (the above lines get called in the componentDidRender lifecycle event of a Stencil web component) and the width on computedStyle actually was updated after being shown initially?

Answer (score 1):

The object printed in browser console will be dynamically updated into latest value when you first expand it.

For example, consider the following one line code

```
const foo = {bar: 0}; console.log(foo); foo.bar = 1;
```

There will be an object **{bar: 0}** printed in the console. However, when you try to expand it in the console, it will show **bar: 1** under it.

So apply this in your case, **computedStyle.width** is **"auto"** immediately after logging. But before you expand it in console, the browser did some calculation and it is changed into **"111.234px"**.

Comment: This is true, but I don't think that's the (only) problem OP is facing. IIRC `getComputedStyle().width` should never return `"auto"`, it would either be the empty string (e.g if the element is detached or display:none), or a `px` value. I may be wrong, but in that case I believe a good answer to this question would be one that finds how they got that value. [_Edit_]: my bad, an inline element and a display:none one does return `"auto"`.

Comment: Thanks guys! The dynamic update, as I guessed already in the post, was one reason, the other was, that I used a Stencil lifecycle hook that, according to the documentation, should be invoked when the DOM is already fully rendered (but wasn't). Check my answer for the details.

Answer (score 0):

The Stencil lifecycle hook to use was componentDidUpdate, this gets fully rendered components (although the manual says componentDidLoad should, too), and just to make sure I don't have anything dynamic going on and get the coordinates for free, I used element.getBoundingClientRect() in place of getComputedStyle. So, I guess, one could say this solves my particular problem, although it does not really feel like a solution, more like a workaround...